# Overlap Layout with ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-relativelayout

Im trying to create the following Layout:

[image]

The border of the RelativeLayout is realized with a rectangle shape as background, but I cannot get the ImageView overlap the RelativeLayout with half of it in and half of it out of the border. Is this even possible with RelativeLayout (And if not: What alternative do I have)?

*layout.xml*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/imageresource"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:padding="@dimen/item_inner_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/item_border"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView">

        <!-- Stuff in the layout -->

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

danijoo

Comment: Very easy - Align both the RelativeLayout and the ImageView to the top of their parent. Play with the margin of the RelativeLayout to be shifted down some dps to match the ImageView's half

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="30dp">

            <!-- add content here -->

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```